# How to open link on specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider on a page, I need the link in that slider to send it to another page with a specific tab open.

I tried to use # 1 at the end of the link however it does not work.

I think i have to use some js to do this, have to put active class on tab and remove the active from first tab. And they will have several sliders that will send to that same page with another open tab.

**SLIDER**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row text-center my-3">
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto central_slider_prod">
          <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100 tamanho_carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <a href="www.link.com/test.php#1" class="d-block col-3"> <img class="img-fluid" src="test1.jpg" /><span>Test 1</span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <a href="www.link.com/test.php#2" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="test2.jpg" /><span>Test 2</span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**TABS**

```
    <div id="exTab2" class="container alinha-tab">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="bt_prod_1">
          <a id="bt_prod_2" class="active" href="#1" data-toggle="tab">
            Test 1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="bt_prod_1">
          <a id="bt_prod_3" href="#2" data-toggle="tab">
            Test 2
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- TAB #1 -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              Test 1
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- TAB #2 -->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              Test 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: maybe you need to add `target=_blank` to the link so it opens on a new tab.

Comment: Take a look at the following resource: http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/jqui_specific.php  To clarify, you are trying to open a tab within a javascript Tabs, not a browser tab, correct?

Comment: Correct coreyg, im trying to do that

Comment: coreyg, i tried that link but without sucess. Can you explain how can i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To open a new tab you add target="_blank" to your anchor link

```
   <a href="www.link.com/test.php#2" target="_blank" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="test2.jpg" /><span>Test 2</span></a>
```

Comment: I dont need to open in new tab browser, need to open in specific tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your js if you use jquery:

```
$(window.location.hash).tab('show');
```